# Magento - How to insert product image in transactional email

Tags: image, email, magento

Basically I would like to include the product image to the New Order Email sent when ordering a product.

I started in email/order/items/order/default.phtml with this code

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
```

How do I use this code to fetch the image?

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(250)
```

thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since I found the answer early I should post it here to help other s in need.. :)

```
<?php //added for sending image with order
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
        ->load($_item->getProductId()); 
    ?>  
        <p align="center"><img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(50); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="" /></p>
```

just put this snippet below

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
```

NOTE: For gmail users, don't forget to enable Display Image.. :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Does this also work?

```
$product = $_item->getProduct()
```

Comment: Probably not, because we need the getOrder method to get the products ordered.. (haven't tested this, not sure)

Answer (score 0):

### Get Image in sale order email

Please view below code :

1. $_item = $block->getItem();
2. $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
3. $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
4. $imageHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
5. $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getFile())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();

End add : `<img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="" />`

---

Good look !