# Display New Product in Transactional Email

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I created a static block where I inserted a new product block. Products New From Date are already set.

I pasted the new product block in the Transactional Email Template as below :

{{block   type="cms/block" block_id="enewarrival " }}

Every other content except the "new product" images from the new product static block get displayed when the Transactional Email template is previewed or sent as an email

1. How can new product images be displayed in Transactional Email to be sent out when there are new product?

OR

2. How can a "Catalog New product list" widget be displayed in Transactional email?

NOTE:  I have viewed this link: 
[Magento - How to insert product image in transactional email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103321/magento-how-to-insert-product-image-in-transactional-email)

when I insert image normaly in the the static block inserted into the  transactional email, the image is displayed. The issue is with New product images getting displayed